# Hibernate internal functioning

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc

I'm working on Spring + Hibernate applications. We have applied transaction for service class methods. My questions

1. Can hibernate execute all db statements of the service method with single connection/session or it uses multiple connections? If it uses multiple connections is it possible to rollback db statements over multiple connections in case of any runtime exceptions?
2. Suppose if the service method's business logic execution takes more time than removeAbandonedTimeout value, how does the commit/rollback happens on abandoned connection?

Please correct me if i'm wrong any where. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:-**

If the query takes more time than removeAbandonedTimeout it throws exception. Suppose my service method has two db calls, between those two calls some business logic (with no db calls) is there. Before executing the first query it creates db connection, assume first db call took 1 second, and then the business logic execution took 60 seconds. If the connection is abandoned it this moment (if we set removeAbandonedTimeout to 60 seconds), to execute second db query it creates another connection, right? If the second query execution fails it has to rollback first query as they both share same transaction. How could it happen with abandoned connection?

Comment: When a transaction timeout or an exception occurs Hibernate will roll back the entire transaction regardless of the number of connections.

Comment: @Transactional on method will open one session, that is one connection.
Commit/rollback will be done on method exit. default is for every runtimeException -> rollback

Comment: @Zeromus ok. But what if the connection becomes abandoned in the middle of the execution ?

Comment: suppose it will throw a jdbc4.CommunicationsException and from there rollback transaction

Comment: My question updated, please check.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hibernate will do what you told it to :

When integrating with spring, it will use spring managed transaction. Check where you are opening / closing tx (use of @Transactional on public method or directly using TransactionTemplate) : all hibernate queries inside will run in the same transaction.

2. This is a question related to your connection pool (dbcp ?). Do not activate the `removeAbandonedTimeout` flag : `removeAbandonedOnMaintenance` : from documentation :

> Setting one or both of these to true can recover db connections 
>    from poorly written applications which fail to close connections.

If you are using typical spring / hibernate coding pattern, you are not poorly writting your application (from a database resource point of view), so no need to activate this flag : let your long running thread keep it's transaction. If an operation is running so slow without running any db query (that it would have triggered dbcp cleanup), you have two options :

- Don't keep the connection to the database : cut your transaction in two : one before the long running process, one after
- If you need to keep the tx open (because you have database lock you do not want to lose for example), try to optimize the code in between using cpu sampling tool for example.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. My question is updated, could you please kindly check my updates.

Comment: i don't know, but honestly, you should not activate "abandonned" action collecting : the db connection pool has no way to know if the connection is really abandonned. And even if your second query is allowed to run using a new connection (and a new transaction), the first one will have been rolled back, which might make the whole process seems to work but with inconsistent data.

Answer (score 0):

Answers for your questions:

1. With single connection we can execute all db statements of service.We cannot rollback db statements over multiple connections at a time.
2. In general the removeAbandonedTimeout value should be set to the longest running query your applications might have.If the removeAbandonedTimeout exceeds and if removeAbandoned = true, the db connections can be recovered.